# Wordpress website is not loading on iOS after migration

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wsod

I recently migrated my website http://predictsense.io/ from test server to production. The website is working fine on all the major desktop browsers and Android phones however ios Safari is not loading the website I am just getting a white screen. If I fetch /wp-admin login page is loading properly but the home page of the website is not loading.

There is no error on the website. Also, no console errors are showing on chrome.

Comment: as it stands, this question has nothing to do with programming

Comment: **too broad**. it's more looks like the problem with your IOS Safari browser. provide more info like any error logs and etc.

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan There are no errors I cleared the browser cache. The page is loading on safari web browser on MacBook. If I fetch /wp-admin login page is loading properly but the website is not loading.

Comment: the prbolem is that in any other browser it shows without errors, but with your browser you saw white screen. for ex., I looked at your website through several browsers, and all of them shows without any errors( only fonts cant load due to `cross-origin` error )

Comment: This issue seems to be with server-side caching done by Managed Hosting servers of Godaddy. Working out on that issue.